# listen to any port in tcp server

Tags: sockets, tcp, bind, listen

I Work with a Hardware and I can ping with it.I write a TCP server App that listen to special port and and special IP (My hardware Ip). the hardware send data in ip and port that I don't know, so how can I get data from my hardware with TCP protocol?

Comment: You can listen for connections on any interface (address) but not on any port. The port number have to be fixed, and you have to tell the clients (one way or another) what port to connect to. If the clients attempt to connect to a specific port and it can't be change, you need to figure out which port it is and use that.

Comment: You can find out what port it's trying to connect to by sniffing the network. Or from its documentation. Or the vendor.